# Multiple Integer Inputs in one line Python

Tags: python, string, list, split

The input is integers separated by a space in the form below:
180 141 142 175 162

```
busnumbers = input().split()

for n in busnumbers:
    n = int(n)
```

I want busnumbers = [ 180,141,142,175,162] 
Instead, I have ['180','141','142','175','162']
Why isn't the conversion working?

Comment: Even if you put integers for your input, they will always be read as a string. You have to explicitly convert them to an `int`. Look at the link provided.

Answer (score 1):

Because `n` variable that you apply `int()` is not transform data in list. It just transforms each data in the loop.

If you want to use above code it would be

`for i,v in enumerate(busnumbers):
    busnumbers[i] = int(v)`

`busnumbers = list(map(int, input().split()))`

Comment: but my question is why isn't the conversion method stated above working

Comment: @NayaKeto Answer in edited comment.

Comment: You can transform the data in the list using his approach if the objects are mutable, but here, integers are not.